# Ask for Chrome Desktop to run Flash Player

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I don't know why, but recently google chrome is not running my flash vídeos anymore, It does run if I enable flash player.

Back then, Chrome itself asked for those permissions, but now it's not asking :(

Is there a way (an API) so I can ask for those permission to run?

Thanks.

Comment: Got a link to see/test issue in action? Did you make the Flash app (you have source code to edit)? Also make sure your SWF is displayed at minimum size of : **width=800** and **height=600** or higher numbers. Also having `https` server for SWF location helps.

Comment: Sure, I got a sample video, here: http://54.94.135.181/embed/vod/DmCiuAYFg I can play it if I explicit declare that I want to run flash, but I don't want to make all my user follow the step by step to activate flash support on chrome :(

Comment: There is no `.swf` (Flash) file listed in the source code of that page, that's why Chrome does not ask.

Comment: Did you solve this? I really need to know!! thankx

Answer (score 1):

Did you try following this: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784?hl=en ?
Or this: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-chrome.html

Edit: removed questionable info source. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Forget those _The Verge_ or _CNet_ articles... if the link isn't from **Adobe**, **Google**, **Mozilla**, or **Microsoft** etc then ignore their speculative talk. Stick to official sites of the specific technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Try this cheat:

```
/**
 * Tries to show browser's promt for enabling flash
 *
 * Chrome starting from 56 version and Edge from 15 are disabling flash
 * by default. To promt user to enable flash, they suggest to send user to
 * flash player download page. Then this browser will catch such request
 * and show a promt to user:
 * https://www.chromium.org/flash-roadmap#TOC-Developer-Recommendations
 * In this method we are forcing such promt by navigating user to adobe
 * site in iframe, instead of top window
 */
function requestFlashPermission() {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.src = 'https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer';
    iframe.sandbox = '';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    document.body.removeChild(iframe);
}


var isNewEdge = (navigator.userAgent.match(/Edge\/(\d+)/) || [])[1] > 14;
var isNewSafari = (navigator.userAgent.match(/OS X (\d+)/) || [])[1] > 9;
var isNewChrome = (navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(e|ium)\/(\d+)/) || [])[2] > 56
    && !/Mobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
var canRequestPermission = isNewEdge || isNewSafari || isNewChrome;

if (!swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion('10') && canRequestPermission) {
    requestFlashPermission();
    // Chrome requires user's click in order to allow iframe embeding
    $(window).one('click', requestFlashPermission);
}
```

Based on: https://www.chromium.org/flash-roadmap#TOC-Developer-Recommendations